# Find unix command gives "Not a directory" error message

Tags: macos, unix, find, runtime-error

To locate files on my computer that have a given string, I execute the following command in the root directory using a Unix bash shell:

```
bash$ sudo find . -name file-name-to-be-searched
```

I then get a list of files but also the following:

```
find: ./dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: ./dev/fd/4: Not a directory
```

This is puzzling because there is also `./dev/fd/5` which does not appear listed and for all three of them, when I do:

```
bash$ cd ./dev/fd
bash$ cat 3
```

(or 4 or 5)

I get:

```
Bad file descriptor
```

Bash gives the same message with:

```
bash$ cd 3
```

This is the contents of the directory:

```
bash$ pwd
/dev/fd
bash$ ls -l
total 0
crw--w----  1 bro   tty     16,   5 Oct 26 02:54 0
crw--w----  1 bro   tty     16,   5 Oct 26 02:54 1
crw--w----  1 bro   tty     16,   5 Oct 26 02:54 2
dr--r--r--  1 root  wheel         0 Oct 21 09:15 3
dr--r--r--  1 root  wheel         0 Oct 21 09:15 4
dr--r--r--  1 root  wheel         0 Oct 21 09:15 5
```

I would like to know why I get this behavior, why I don't see a similar message for file `./dev/fd/5` and if this may be an indicator that I am not searching the entire directory structure. If there is some sort of corrupted file that this signals, is there a way not to list it?

Comment: The `/dev` directory just contains pseudo-files representing the hardware (and software) devices attached to your Mac. Either use `-prune` with your `find` or discard the errors with `sudo find ... 2> /dev/null`

Comment: Or only search in more likely places `find /Users /etc /usr /Applications -name ...`

Answer (score 0):

To address the last part of the question, as suggested by [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell)'s comment (thank you!), adding [`2> /dev/null`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350208/what-does-2-dev-null-mean) gets rid of the error messages:

`bash$ sudo find . -name file-name-to-be-searched 2> /dev/null`

However, it leaves us a bit in the dark as to why there is no error message for the file descriptor `/dev/fd/5` and its possible impacts in the execution of `find`.